# How to loop extracted div with selenium in Python?

Tags: html, selenium, python-2.7

In my previous step i had a problem to get text from div, after few hours finally i got what i want, but the next step was not even easier, becouse i want to loop that print text (variable).

I hope that you are indulgent guys and i will not get downvoted just becouse I am new with python. 
This is a part what i got already:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://example.com//')
botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
print botloc

def repeat():
    while 1 == 1:
        botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
        print botloc
```

A real website address has been changed as a precaution.

The first half part of a code works well, but the second one not. 
After typing `repeat` in Shell, the respond is `<function repeat at 0x015BBFB0>`. It's not text from div, for me (newbie) it looks like object value or something... When the respond after `print botloc` is `u'26,40'`, then why my `def repeat()` is not the same? How can i fix that?

Comment: You're typing `repeat`? Don't you need to type `repeat()` to evaluate the function? Functions are first class objects in Python (so far as I know). You can pass them around like any other object. So typing `repeat` without parentheses gives you the function object that the `repeat` variable holds.

Comment: Why does your ``repeat`` function contain a while loop (which never ends btw)? What exactly you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @lqc my `repeat` function contain a while loop, becouse I want to achieve the actual text contained in a div that reflects the coordinates of my hero on the square map in web browser. The coordinates will be used to communicate with bot, giving him his actuall possition. Probably my logic is broken and i go circuitous route, but thats still my own logic and i dont know the other way to get coordinates. You know unexpected Sometimes is the best! But thanks to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `selenium.py` with the following code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.helloworld.com/')
print driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='privacy']").text

def repeat():
    while 1 == 1:
        print driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='privacy']").text

repeat() # this is what you need!
```

Change the url to your own one, and change the locators to yours, i.e. `driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text`.

Then from command line: run `python selenium.py`, it should be working

However, I doubt your testing logic though, if your DOM changes during the loop, exception will be thrown.

Comment: Infinite loops aren't very useful in tests.

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't thinked i was so close to be right with that code. Thanks for fixing. So now, when i move my hero, the otput is: `26,19
26,19
26,19
26,20
26,20
26,20
26,20
26,21
26,21
26,21
26,21
26,22
26,22
26,22
26,23
26,23
26,24
26,24
26,25` coordinates are updated very fast, I think now i will put some time function to create it for every 0,2 sec :)